# Desktop doesn't show anything

Tags: unity

My Desktop doesn't show anything:

This was after changing the system language. When the message appeared if I want to change the path names of the home directories, I pressed "Yes".

My files for the desktop are stored in `$HOME/Desktop`, which is also in 
`/home/<username>/.config/user-dirs.dirs`.

I assume the problem in some unity setting file, because when I want to create a new folder manually on the desktop via right-click an error occurs:

> Error when getting information for file '$home/Schreibtisch':No such file or directory

This is the path which has been specified as folder for the desktop files in my former language. However, I can't find the file, where this path is stored in and my desktop keeps empty.
Can you help me?

Here the output of `/home/<username>/.config/user-dirs.dirs`:

```
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Downloads"
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/Templates"
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/Public"
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/Documents"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/Music"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Pictures"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/Videos"
```

When I create the directory `$home/Schreibtisch` and I place a file in it, it appears on the desktop.

Comment: can you access `/home/Schreibtisch`

Comment: No but I could create it and the files there would be shown, but not a perfect solution

Comment: I'm not sure what you've done here. The default location for Desktop under Ubuntu is `/home/username/Desktop` and /home/<username>/.config/user-dirs.dirs. doesn't exist in a normal installation.

Comment: Can you add please in your question the total contents of your $HOME/.config/user-dirs.dirs file?

Comment: @Videonauth added the output of the file, took a bit longer as I hadn't the ubuntu pc ready

Comment: Check the `/etc/xdg/user-dirs.defaults` if there the names alswell have changed properly.